# Coroutine different behaviour when called from another script

Tags: unity, c#

I am quite new with game dev, specially with unity. In order to understand how it works, I decided to start small with a pong game.

I have a **Ball script**, which in the **Update()** method move the ball depending to the speed, and if a player score, it increment a score field and reset the ball to the center (and stop the ball for 2 seconds) trough a coroutine function.

**Ball script:**

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    float speed;
    int isMoving = 1;
    float radius;
    Vector2 direction;
    Vector2 startPosition;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        direction = Vector2.one.normalized;
        radius = transform.localScale.x / 2; // half the width
        startPosition = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(direction * speed * isMoving * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.y < GameManager.bottomLeft.y + radius && direction.y < 0) {
            direction.y = -direction.y;
        } 
        if (transform.position.y > GameManager.topRight.y - radius && direction.y > 0) {
            direction.y = -direction.y;
        }

        // Ball go in any goal
        if (transform.position.x < GameManager.bottomLeft.x + radius && direction.x < 0) {
            GameManager.instance.addScorePlayer("p2");
            StartCoroutine( Reset() );
        } 
        if (transform.position.x > GameManager.topRight.x - radius && direction.x > 0) {
            GameManager.instance.addScorePlayer("p1");
            StartCoroutine( Reset() );
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Reset() {
        isMoving = 0;
        transform.position = startPosition;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        isMoving = 1;
    }
}
```

This works as expected! The score is incremented, the ball go back to the center, wait for 2 seconds and start to move again.
However, now I want to call the **Ball Reset() method** trough my **GameManager** (because I want to code some logics inside the GameManager).

**So here are my modifications:**

**Ball script:** (remove Reset() calls and update Reset() method to public)

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ...

        // Ball go in any goal
        if (transform.position.x < GameManager.bottomLeft.x + radius && direction.x < 0) {
            GameManager.instance.addScorePlayer("p2");
        } 
        if (transform.position.x > GameManager.topRight.x - radius && direction.x > 0) {
            GameManager.instance.addScorePlayer("p1");
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator Reset() {
        isMoving = 0;
        transform.position = startPosition;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

        isMoving = 1;
    }
```

**GameManager script:**

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Ball ball;

    ...

    void Start()
    {   
        ...

        // Create ball
        Instantiate (ball);

    }

    public void addScorePlayer(string player) {

        if (player == "p1") {
            score1 += 1;
            score1Text.text = score1.ToString();
        }
        else if (player == "p2") {
            score2 += 1;
            score2Text.text = score2.ToString();
        }

        StartCoroutine( ball.Reset() );
    }
```

This doesn't work for some reason. The ball don't come back to the center, and the score increment infinitely.

I have tried many things and I have figured out that the behaviour is the same as running the **Reset()** method trough the Ball script without the StartCoroutine.

So it seems that the Coroutine don't work properly if called trough the GameManager ?
I have also printed some logs into my console in the **Ball.Reset()** method, and the method is being called, so I don't understand why the ball don't go back to the center.

(Link to my public github repository https://github.com/Sewake/Unity2D-Pong)

Comment: Do you observe any errors in your console log when running with this code?

Comment: No there is no errors in my console, only prints that I have wrote into my Ball.Reset() method :/